# assetic symfony2: html content inside css files

Tags: html, css, symfony, assetic

I'm trying to import css file inside twig file using assetic.

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/sfeuser/css/bootstrap.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"  type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

when I load the page. it was only HTML without style
and when I checked the css file. I found out that it contains HTML content of the page loaded.

Comment: Can you explain a bit clearer what is happening? Are you saying that HTML content is appearing in the css file?

Comment: exactly !! there's no CSS code in the loaded bootstrap.css file .. only the HTML code of the loaded page ..
Here's the steps I followed:
I copied the css folder in Resources/public of SFEUserBundle
then I launched the command assets:install target [--symlink] to move them to the web/bundles folder
when I loaded the page .. I got this problem
Is this has any thing to do with phpstorm ?

Comment: I solved the problem .. it's in security.yml I forgot to remove a firewall that was applied on the whole application .. that's why when the browser try to access bootstrap.css .. it's redirected to the login page that's why I get the HTML content of the login page in the CSS file

Comment: Glad you solved it! You can post that answer to your own question now, for anyone else with a similar problem that comes across this page.

Comment: Ok I'll do it ! Thank you @SuperBiasedMan !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the security.yml file I forgot to remove a firewall with authentification that was applied on the whole application.

That's why when the browser tries to access the CSS file it gets redirected to the login page. Therefore the HTML content of the login page was found in the CSS file.